# Execute a Stored Procedure Inside a View?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I started working for a company a few weeks ago, and have inherited a crazy mess of databases. I'm currently working on designing the new systems to replace their older ones. The previous developer created a ton of views that are entirely identical, with the only differences being the conditions within the `WHERE` clause. In my attempt to cleanup the source, I was attempting to create a stored procedure that returns the table based on the given conditions, so I can compact 250 views into a single stored procedure.

Honestly, the only reason I'm doing this is so when I start transitioning over to the newer databases and front-ends, I have some pre-made stored procedures to use rather than a jumbled mess of views.

Is there any way that I can execute the stored procedures I created inside of the currently existing views, so I don't have to modify their front end (A series of access databases connected to SQL Server through ODBC)?

My stored procedure looks something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BusDuctQueries.CMSF_Current_Mod @ModNumber VARCHAR(255)
AS
   SELECT        [Date], [Name], [Mod], [Cell], [Row], [Section],
    [Phase A Breaker Amps], [Phase B Breaker Amps], [Phase C Breaker Amps], 
    [Phase A Actual Amps], [Phase B Actual Amps], [Phase C Actual Amps], 
    [PDU # 1], [Bus Duct # 1], 
    [Bus Duct # 1 Phase A Current Load], [Bus Duct # 1 Phase B Current Load], [Bus Duct # 1 Phase C Current Load], 
    [PDU # 2], [Bus Duct # 2], 
    [Bus Duct # 2 Phase A Current Load], [Bus Duct # 2 Phase B Current Load], [Bus Duct # 2 Phase C Current Load], 
    [Sort 1], [Sort 2], [Average Load], [Percent Used], [Percent Remaining], [KW Used], 
    CONVERT(NUMERIC(18, 2), [Derated KW Left]) AS [Derated KW Left], 
    CONVERT(NUMERIC(18, 2), [True KW Left]) AS [True KW Left], 
    CASE WHEN [PDU # 1] LIKE '%A%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS UPSSort
FROM            BusDuctQueries.[CMSF Current]
WHERE        ([Mod] = @ModNumber) AND  (Cell NOT LIKE '%WP%')
```

Comment: Why not just transition to the stored procedure when you go to the newer databases and front-ends?  Plugging into ugly code to test is ugly. Put your effort into testing on the new app.

Comment: @Blam this is more of a technique for me to abstract away some of the current code that's in place to make it easier to start migrating things over to my database. As I can figure out what's going on behind the scenes, it makes it easier for me to make changes without disrupting their current workflow, until the new front end is ready.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot call a stored proc from inside a view. It is not supported. However you can make views call other views, or [table-valued user-defined functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

For the latter you must make sure that you're using [inline functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189294%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Otherwise, any subsequent clauses like `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` to will be performed on the dynamically produced resultset instead. Thus, you won't benefit from index searches and the likes. This may have a huge impact on performance.

Comment: Actually, if it's converted to inline TVF (as opposed to multi-statement TVF), it will not have the impact you're describing at all.

Comment: @dean that's right, thanks. I rarely use UDF for this kind of thing, I much prefer making views over base views.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this, both with their pros and cons:

1. Use [OPENROWSET](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) / [OPENQUERY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx). These allow you do do a SELECT on anything you want, but
   it might have security implications that you don't like. That might not be an issue if
   this is a short-term solution and afterwards you can undo the allowing of "Ad Hoc 
   Distributed Queries". But this is the easiest to set up, especially if the result sets 
   vary between the procs (assuming that there are multiple procs).
2. Write a SQLCLR TVF that executes the procedure. This can be done in SAFE mode if the
   Stored Procedures are read-only (i.e. no INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE statements and most
   likely no CREATE #Tmp statements). I wrote an article showing an example of this:
   [Stairway to SQLCLR Level 2: Sample Stored Procedure and Function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/105841/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some heavy lifting, perhaps manipulating table variables, using while loops and so on, then use a function and reference that from your view.

You can't use a stored procedure because stored procs are allowed to edit your data - as such if you could reference them from a view, then a select could have side effects - which is not allowed.

Comment: These views are used entirely for pulling reports. So inside the access front end, the previous developer set the data source for each report to each individual view. The difference inside each view is merely something like `WHERE (Mod = 'D1')` or `WHERE (Mod = 'D2')` etc, so I was looking for a method of essentially down sizing the code using stored procedures, so when I move over to the new front end (an ASP.net powered webpage), I merely have to call the new stored procedure rather than each one of these hundreds of views.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert procedures like this into inline TVFs, also known as parameterized views. The body of the view will remain identical to what you have in the procedure.

Selecting from views/TVFs is different than executing stored procedures, so you might have to change the front end anyway. In any case, someone will have to supply values for the parameters.